# How to understand a regex pattern?

Tags: regex

I need to understand a pattern like this: `^9(ab|cd|ef?)$`

I have some examples of strings passing and not passing this pattern:

```
 9 - NO
 9cd - YES
 9e - YES
 9acef - NO
```

I don't know why third example was accepted and the fourth was not. 
I see the pattern like so: `9` then `a` then (`b or c`) then (`d or e`) then `f` (zero or one times). But I think than my understanding is incorrect. Can someone explain me how to see it?

Comment: You confuse `then` (concatenation) with `or` (`|`). What you described would be `9a(b|c)(d|e)f`

Comment: Sites like https://regex101.com/ are a great help for this sort of thing, as it can break down your regex and show what parts match/don't match

Comment: Here's a link to this regular expression on regex101 https://regex101.com/r/lZ1bJ5/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I see the pattern like so:  9 then a then (b or c) then (d or e) then f (zero or one times).

Wrong. It's actually like 9 then `ab` or `cd` or `ef` or `e` and a end of the line boundary. So this regex would match `9e` but not of `9acef`. The max and min characters which are allowed after 9 would be 2 (*ab,cd,ef*) or 1 (*e*)
 , ie, not more than 2. `?` here would turn the previous token as optional, `ef?` matches `ef` or `e`.

Comment: ok, so an alternative sign include blocks of signs. thank you

Answer (score 1):

The pipe means OR. `(ab|cd|ef?)` means either ab OR cd OR e followed maybe by an f. One of the alternatives has to be present, but multiple alternatives cannot be present.

The ^ and $ are anchors that tell where the start and end of the input have to be. The $ anchor is saying that the end of input must immediately follow the content that matches `(ab|cd|ef?)`.

- 9 : no alternatives are present, this doesn't match.
- 9cd : the cd alternative is present, so this matches.
- 9e: the e and 0 of more fs alternative is present, this matches.
- 9acef: two alternatives are present, and the end of the input doesn't come until after ef; since the regex is specifying that the end of input must come after exactly one of the alternatives, and two alternatives appear, this doesn't match.

Answer (score 1):

`^9(ab|cd|ef?)$` translates to:

`9`, followed by `ab` or `cd` or `ef` or `e` only.

The pattern matching your expectation is:

`9a(b|c)(d|e)f?$`

Answer (score 1):

`9(ab|cd|ef?)`
means: **9** followed by either **ab** or **cd** or **ef** or **e** (since the f is optional, incicated by `?`.

`^`and `$` mark the beginning and the end of the string, respectively.

Hint: Many Regex-Testers (e.g. [regexr.com](http://www.regexr.com/)) provide an explanation of the typed regex on mouseover.